# Querying last 30 days date range with Mongoid and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, date, range

How do I go about querying a date range (of say the last 30 days from now) with Mongoid and Ruby?

I need to end up with an array or hash like the following:

```
{
    15 => 300,
    14 => 23,
    13 => 23
    ...
    30 => 20  # Goes over into previous month
    28 => 2
}
```

I am currently storing each document with a DateTime instance as well as a unix timestamp Integer field.

The keys in the above hash are the days and the values are the sum of all sales for those days.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's how to do it all in rubyland:

```
sales_by_date = Hash.new(0)

Sale.where(:created_at.gte => (Date.today - 30)).order_by(:created_at, :desc).each do |s|
  sales_by_date[s.created_at.strftime("%m-%d")] += 1
end
```

This will create a hash with "month-day" keys, reason is that some months have fewer than 30 days and will result in a key collision if the query is always 30.

If you want a different range, change the query:

```
# Between 10 and 20 days ago
start_day       = 10
end_day         = 20

Sale.where(:created_at.gte => (Date.today - end_day), :created_at.lte => (Date.today - start_day))
```

Change `created_at` to whatever the name of your datetime field is.

Comment: If use `2012-06-16` instead of `(Date.today - 30)` then how write query?

Comment: @harsh4u: Convert the string to a Date object first.  `Date.parse("2012-06-16")`

Comment: this is far from perfect solution, the answers below are way better.

Comment: Sale.where(:end_date.gte => (Date.today), :begin_date.lte => (Date.today)).order(begin_date: :desc)

Answer (score 34):

There's a simpler way:

```
Sale.where(created_at: (30.days.ago..Time.now))
```

Adjust time range to suit.

Comment: This requires ActiveSupport for the .days.ago portion

Comment: I don't think you can add multiple params with the hash syntax this way. Might be wrong though.

Comment: @AshBlue - it's a single argument, of type Range. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html

Comment: `Range` in ruby is very **costly**. Although nice syntax, I'd choose do the `gte` and `lte`

Comment: @oma - could you give some info/link why ruby ranges are costly, especially in that context (mongodb query)?

Comment: @oma Range in ruby is not costly at all. It's converting a range into an array that's very costly, but ORMs should be able to take a range and convert it into either a "BETWEEN ... AND" (sql) or a pair ($lte, $gte) (mongodb).

Comment: In Mongoid, this does create a selector: `selector: {"created_at"=>{"$gte"=>2016-11-25 15:43:56 UTC, "$lte"=>2016-12-25 15:43:56 UTC}}`

Comment: @tomblomfield - In Mongoid 5.1.3, this is emitting an array of Sales. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

You can also write the query by using the `between` method like:

```
Sale.between(created_at: (30.days.ago..Time.now))
```

Answer (score 2):

**What if you forgot to put timestamps in your model? :(**

No problem! Just use the timestamp in the [BSON:ObjectId](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/bson.html)

**Get Sales in the last 30 days.**

```
Sale.where(:id.gte => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_time((Date.today - 30).to_time))
```

Since the `id` field is index, this may very well be the fastest query.

Need a date range? Cake.

**Get Sales from last month.**

```
Sale.and(
  {:id.gte => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_time((Date.today.prev_month.beginning_of_month).to_time)},
  {:id.lte => Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_time((Date.today.prev_month.end_of_month).to_time)}
)
```

Of course this example assumes Rails date helpers...

Comment: I think this is more better answer. It is more difficult but it have nice performance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this for example by doing a `map_reduce` call over your collection with a map function only emitting the relevant entries (the ones whose date value is greater than whatever condition you give it).

Try something like this:

```
map = "function () { emit( {this.date.getDate(), {}} )}"
reduce = "function (key, values) { return {date: key, count: values.length } }"

collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, {query: {"date": {"$gt": 30.days.ago } } })
```

That might work.